# Success/Failure return type for Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I have wrote Generic Methods for Get,Post and Put. An example of **Get Generic Method** is :

```
 public async Task<object> GetAsync<T>(string uri, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
        {
            return await ProcessAsync<T>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
        }
    }
```

and **ProcessAync** is :

```
public async Task<object> ProcessAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken);
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Request Succeeded");
            var dezerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = namingStrategy
                }
            };
            T responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), dezerializerSettings);
            return responseModel;
        }
        else
        {
            return await GetFailureResponseModel(response);

        }
    }
```

than i am calling this get method like that in my SingletonClass

```
 public async Task<object> GetShops(string category)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(GetShops));
        return await _client.GetAsync<ShopsResponseModel>($"v2/shops?category={WebUtility.UrlEncode(category)}");
    }
```

And this method is called in my Controller like this

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetShops([FromQuery(Name = "category")]string category)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetShops(category);
        return ParseResponse<ShopsResponseModel>(response);
    }
```

and **ParseResponse** is

```
 protected ActionResult<object> ParseResponse<T>(object response)
    {
        if (response.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return Ok(response);
        }
        else
        {
            return Error(response);
        }
    }
```

As the call chain shows, I am expecting other SuccessModel or FailureModel in my Api response and due to that I have to use **object** as return type. But I have feeling that I shouldn't be using **object** type for return. FYI above chain works fine. I am just looking for more refactoring or enhancement of my current flow. looking for more elegant solution to this problem. Please do suggest any other solution for my problem.

**Update**
I tried @ChrisPratt suggestion of using Interface, but that solution is not working or maybe i am doing it wrong. So i created this empty Interface

```
public interface IResult
{
}
```

And I extended Both my `ShopResponseModel` and `FailureResponseModel` from `IResult` Interface, and updated methods like this.

```
 public async Task<IResult> GetShops(string category)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("ClubMatas outgoing request: {RequestName}", nameof(GetShops));
        return await _client.GetAsync<IResult>($"v2/shops?category={WebUtility.UrlEncode(category)}");
    }
```

and

```
 public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
        {
            return await ProcessAsync<T>(requestMessage, namingStrategy);
        }
    }
```

and I updated `ProcessAsync` return type from *object* to *T*. But getting errors.

Comment: Why not just throw an exception in case something went wrong?

Comment: But I need that failureResponse at Mobile End as well, Because it contain custom messages related to error and how to fix it as well. So throwing exception won't help me in that case.

Comment: A generic method shouldn't have to use `object`. It should accept the return type as a type parameter too. As for using Result types like Rust, F#, all you need is for both concrete types to inherit from the same base interface/type. It doesn't even have to have any members

Comment: `ParseResponse` itself can be eliminated once you deal with types instead of `object`. You can combine this with C# 7's pattern matching to access the concrete object if needed

Comment: @Shabirjan you haven't posted the definitions of the success/failure types. `GetShops` shows that instead of `object` you should be using `ShopsResponseModel` or something that contains a `ShopsResponseModel`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Success type in case of GetShops will be `ShopResponseModel` and in case of Failure will be `FailureResponseModel` .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You said that GetShops should be using `ShopResponseModel` but it can also return FailureModel then how I should set return type only for SuccessModels?

Comment: @Shabirjan you still don't need `object`. The easiest solution would be to use a common interface eg `IResult` with no members.

Comment: Can you share bit more?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you said :` A generic method shouldn't have to use object. It should accept the return type as a type parameter too. ` but as i said i am expecting either SuccessModel which i am passing as TypeParameter and FailureResponseModel as well.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have feeling that I shouldn't be using object type for return.

Yes. Don't use `object` for return values. It's virtually useless as a return type. What you should be doing is returning an interface. For example, you can do something like:

```
public interface IResponseStatusModel
{
    bool Succeeded { get; }
    int StatusCode { get; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then:

```
public class SuccessModel : IResponseStatusModel

public class FailureModel : IResponseStatusModel
```

Then, you can return `IResponseStatusModel`, and based on the interface, you'll be able to interact with any property or method defined on the interface, regardless of which model you actually return.

However, you really shouldn't have separate classes for success/failure. Creating an interface that can generically allow you to interact with either one is going to lead to blurring the lines between the two, anyways. Instead, you should simply return a single model type, that has properties like the above and maybe a list property for errors and such. For example:

```
public class ProcessResult
{
    public ProcessResult(int statusCode) : this(statusCode, null) {}

    public ProcessResult(int statusCode, IEnumerable<string> errors)
    {
        Succeeded = statusCode < 300;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Errors = errors;
    }

    public bool Succeeded { get; private set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; private set; }
}
```

That's a *very* basic example. You might want to build it out more and provide a more robust solution for determining whether the task succeeded or not. The general idea is that you provide as much relevant information as possible concerning the result of the operation. Then, in your code, you can simply branch on `Succeeded` and then handle the situation accordingly:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // do something on success
}
else
{
    // do something on failure
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. But I have couple of questions, First Why Interface has parameters? Right now in Controller I am returning either SuccessModel or FailureResponseModel. Secondly how can I add this Interface in my Generic calls flow?

Comment: tried your solution of using Interface  but getting errors. Check updated section in my question.